# mysql_insert_id() always returning 0

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-insert-id

I have this code that I need to populate through a form a new line in two tables with a foreign key constrain. This doe refer to the first insert only, and I need identify the last_id generated to use it for the related table. But $last_id returns Always zero notwistanding the new record is create.

```
   //Connect to Database 
 $con=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_pass,$db_name); 
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }
// Database connesso

// Devo inserire il record in Documents prima perché é quello che genera la Primary Key

 $sql=" INSERT INTO Documents (doc_name, doc_type, doc_manager, doc_pointer) VALUES ('$upload_name','Privacy','Agente di riferimento','$pic')";
 $last_id = mysql_insert_id();
 Echo "Last Protocol Number =".$last_id."<br>";
```

Absolutely similar code works perfectly in another script thus should not be an php version issue:

> //Writes the information to the database 
>    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `documents` (doc_name,doc_type,doc_manager,doc_pointer) VALUES ('$name', '$type', '$manager', '$pic')") ; 
>    $id = mysql_insert_id();
>    Echo "Last Protocol Number =".$id."
> ";

Not able to understand where the issue is.

Comment: SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()

Comment: So... mysql or mysqli...? Which is it?

Comment: You're not actually running your $sql. There is no `mysql_query` in your example code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to run your query *and* you've mixed `mysql_` and `mysqli_` APIs

```
$sql=" INSERT INTO Documents (doc_name, doc_type, doc_manager, doc_pointer) VALUES ('$upload_name','Privacy','Agente di riferimento','$pic')";
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
```

FYI, this example has no error handling. You should add it.

Comment: OP seems to be half-using mysqli already...

Comment: Totally missed that when I saw they didn't run their query. Answer updated.

Comment: In reality there is mysqli_query execution but was afterward mysqli_insert_id, thus you are rigth that's the reason why it was not working.